# Splitting an array of strings

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to split an array of strings where each of them have "," as the delimiter. I obtained the array of strings after an earlier split using regex for the pattern of new line. The input is from a text file and here is the pattern as in the text file.

Contents of my text file

```
"first", "second"
"third", "fourth", "fifth"
"Sixth", "seventh"
```

Second text file

```
"Color.auto", "(current == ff) && (current == 00)"
"Color.auto", "(current == ff) ? ((Current > 0) && (current < 10))"
```

The code which creates an array of strings split on new line character.

```
StreamReader sr = new stream reader(file.txt);
String data = sr.ReadToEnd();
String pattern = @"\r\n";
String[] result = regex.split(data, pattern);

foreach(string store in result)
{
  String temp = store.split(",".ToCharArray());
}
```

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to split the strings on "," further using "split". I believe it is due to the array of strings which I am trying to split.

Comment: Why did you use `Store` instead of `store`?

Comment: This even doesn't need `regex`, just `Split` method of string would be OK.

Comment: It is "store" itself in my code, it's a mistake when I typed it in here

Comment: @king I want to do the split twice. Once for the newline an the other for ",". That's why I have used regex in the first case and I am trying to use split in the second

Comment: @AjitPeter You can also use `Split` for the first step.

Comment: Is it also a typo that you have `split` instead of `Split` and `tochararray` instead of `ToCharArray`?  Can you paste your actual code, so we know if we're working with syntax errors or other issues?  While I'm at it, in what way is split not working?  Are you doing something more with `temp`?  It gets overwritten each time you go through the loop.

Comment: If your input gets complicated enough, you will need `regex` for splitting your lines, but `String.Split` or `File.ReadLines` are the more reasonable ways to split a big file into multiple lines.

Comment: @scott I currently don't have Internet on my pc. The dictionary keeps on autocorrecting on the tablet. The code is error free apart from the statement in the foreach loop which gives a "best overloaded match for spring.split has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @AjitPeter I thought it looked like autocorrecting.  :-)  I'll edit the syntax to be compilable.  It sounds like you just need the syntax for a new char array as in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Functional style
var tokens = File.ReadLines(file)
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(',')) //split lines on commas
    .Select(token => token.Trim(' ')) //remove spaces around tokens
    .Select(token => token.Trim('"')); //remove quotes around tokens

//Query style
var tokens = from line in File.ReadLines(file)
             from token in line.Split(',')
             select token.Trim(' ').Trim('"');
```

Note this will only work if your quoted strings in the file do not contain commas. If they do, you'll want to look into using regex.

Comment: What is `'\"'`? I think you mean `'"'`

Answer (score 8):

Just use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) with the StringSplitOptions parameter:

```
string[] tokens = data.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n', ',', ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will take your single string and split it based on all linefeed parts as well as all commas.  I threw in the space and tab character as well, though you can remove them if you don't want them.

The second parameter is so that you don't get empty tokens returned, e.g. between `'\r'` and `'\n'`.

**EDIT** Based on your second file, you don't want to remove whitespace, though it looks like you do probably want to remove the quotes.  In that case, your line would be as follows.  (I've split it into two lines just to make it look neater.)

```
char[] delimiters = new char[] { '\r', '\n', ',', '"' };
string[] tokens = data.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: I tried it on a second text file which I have added right now. It alters the output as I need to check for only a single newline at end which is why I used regex.

Comment: @AjitPeter Letting us know what you need is a good way to get what you need.  :-P  In this case, you don't want to remove spaces or tabs, just like Timothy mentioned in his answer regarding commas.  See my edit.

Comment: "@scott" you are really far sighted :-) removing " is what I was looking to do next.

Comment: @AjitPeter This answer still has problems. If the quoted strings in the file have spaces between them, you're going to get garbage whitespace tokens.

Comment: @timothy yes i agree, just checked it using the second text file i have added.

Comment: Why does this answer have so many upvotes? With respect to the question, this answer is outright wrong. It will return single space strings (`" "`) between every two quoted strings. The text file line `"a", "b"` will get you the `tokens` as `["a", " ", "b"]`.